# Деление с остатком uint64_t на 10

Tags: c, алгоритм, binary

На 32-bit микропроцессоре нужна функция (эффективный алгоритм) для получения частного и остатка от деления **uint64_t** на 10 (как всегда для печати).

Полазив по интернету, в http://www.hackersdelight.org/divcMore.pdf нашел лишь нечто похожее (для `uint32_t`) с вот таким кодом

```
unsigned divu10(unsigned n) {
    unsigned q, r;
    q = (n >> 1) + (n >> 2);
    q = q + (q >> 4);
    q = q + (q >> 8);
    q = q + (q >> 16);
    q = q >> 3;
    r = n - q*10;
    return q + ((r + 6) >> 4);
    // return q + (r > 9);
}
```

Для своей цели изменил ее вот так (*фактически, добавил оператор `q = q + (q >> 32);`* :

```
uint64_t divu64_10 (uint64_t n, uint32_t *rem) {
  uint64_t q, r;
  q = (n >> 1) + (n >> 2);
  q = q + (q >> 4);
  q = q + (q >> 8);
  q = q + (q >> 16);
  q = q + (q >> 32);
  q = q >> 3;
  r = n - ((q << 3) + (q << 1));
  *rem = r > 9 ? r - 10 : r;

  //  orig: return q + ((r + 6) >> 4);
  return q + (r > 9);
}
```

Проверил, вводя разные числа вот в таком коде на нормальном 64-бит компе:

```
  unsigned long long v;

  while (scanf("%llu", &v) == 1) {
    unsigned long long d;
    uint32_t r;

    d = divu64_10(v, &r);
    printf("divu10: %llu %u (C: %llu %llu)\n",
       d, r,
       v / 10, v % 10);
  }
```

Похоже, мое изменение работает.

Вопрос, собственно в следующем -- может ли кто-нибудь в самом деле разбирающийся в двоичной арифметике **подтвердить, что `divu64_10()` работает верно?**

Comment: Я погонял минут 15 генератор случайных чисел, ошибок не нашёл. Пусть побегает ещё...

Comment: @VladD, спасибо, но полного перебора тут все равно не дождаться...

Comment: Ну это конечно да. Но всё равно небольшое подтверждение будет.

Comment: А вы вообще поняли, что вы добавили и зачем? Я тут вижу некую апроксимацию с помощью рядов. То, что вы сделали, выглядит лишь повышением точности и, скорее всего, на результат не особо влияет.

Comment: @0andriy, откровенно говоря, я добавил сдвиг по аналогии с тем, как для 32-бит сдвиги идут по степеням двойки до половины разрядности делимого,  в надежде, что с 64-мя битами это тоже сработает. И проверка показала, что вроде  работает. Вот, хотелось бы убедиться, что математически это верное решение.

Comment: 3 / 4 + 3 / 64 + (3 / 4  + 3 / 64) / 256 + ... Очень напоминает непрерывную дробь с известным алгоритмом поиска минимальных числителя и знаменателя рациональных дробей:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction, http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/lib/rational.c

Comment: Ну и чтобы второй раз не вставать: http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/lib/vsprintf.c#L296

Comment: @0andriy, спасибо (конечно, основной вопрос остается), можно будет попробовать. Вот эту ссылку http://www.cs.uiowa.edu/~jones/bcd/decimal.html#sixtyfour (на ней базируется реализация  `put_dec(char *buf, unsigned long long n)`) я видел, но как-то код длинноват показался, стал искать более компактный и вышел на  hackersdelight

Comment: Если доказательств правильности-ошибочности ни у кого нет, то посоветуйте, какие наборы битов стоит проверить перебором.

Comment: Всегда удивлялся почему десятичная печать делается через деление? Не быстрее будет вычитать из числа степени десятки (записанные в таблицу)?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, хороший вопрос. Думаю, код с делением займет меньше памяти. А что быстрее -- 180 циклов  вычитания или 18 циклов деления? Мне кажется, при наличии инструкции деления вычитание проиграет. А сами не хотите проверить?

Comment: Если есть инструкция деления - всё понятно. Но в этом вопросе её нет или она слишком медленная. 18*9 циклов вычитания, из них 9*9  вычитание двойных слов и  9*9 одинарных. Всего 243 для всех девяток в числе. Но можно двоичным поиском уменьшить число вычетаний в два раза. Если выделять цифры группами по шесть штук то выигрыш будет ещё больше.

Comment: @avp, я не против проверить сам. Как ставится задача?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, вы правы, в этом вопросе в 32-bit процессоре нет инструкций умножения и  деления 64-bit данных, которые надо печатать (размещать цифры в памяти).  Вообще-то, скорость не самоцель (очевидно, что проц работает намного быстрее, чем UART на 115200), а вот  память лучше экономить. И учтите, никаких ОС и стандартных библиотек нету. Поэтому сомневаюсь, что можно сейчас тут проверить именно стоявшую 4 года назад задачу. Ну, можно сравнить, насколько способ с вычитаниями (результат в памяти) быстрее способа с приведенными тут функциями деления на обычной x-86 PC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Разберем как работает исходный код.

Он вычисляет `q = n * 0x33333333 >> 33`, что примерно равно `n * 0.0999999999...`.
Затем вычисляет ошибку `n - q*10`, и если она меньше 10, то всё правильно,
если больше 10, то к результату добавляется 1.

Расмотрим значения ошибок.

```
10 * 0x33333333 / 2 ** 33 = 0b00.111111111111111111111111111111110
11 * 0x33333333 / 2 ** 33 = 0b01.000110011001100110011001100110001
19 * 0x33333333 / 2 ** 33 = 0b01.111001100110011001100110011001001
20 * 0x33333333 / 2 ** 33 = 0b01.111111111111111111111111111111100
21 * 0x33333333 / 2 ** 33 = 0b10.000110011001100110011001100101111
...
65530 * 0x33333333 / 2 ** 33 = 6552.999998474261 =
                 0b1100110011000.111111111111111111100110011001110
...
4294967290 * 0x33333333 / 2 ** 33 = 429496728.9 =
 0b11001100110011001100110011000.111001100110011001100110011001110
```

Видно что для `n = 10*d + r`, ошибка равна 10 если r=0.

Можно посчитать, что если бы вместо сдвига было бы деление, то ошибка была бы равна

```
n - n * 10 * 0x33333333 / 2**33 = n / 2 ** 32
```

Так как `n < 2 ** 32`, то ошибка результата не превышает единицу.

---

Для 64 разрядов всё так же, только считаем `n * 0x3333333333333333 >> 65`.

Добавление `q += q >> 32` эквивалентно умножению на `(2**32+1)/2**32`, при этом `(2**32+1)*0x33333333 = 0x3333333333333333`.

Comment: Спасибо!!! Я правильно понял суть вашего ответа, что для 64 бит (добавил к программе из www.hackersdelight.org/divcMore.pdf  `q = q + (q >> 32);`)  все работает верно? (и ответ можно принять (а также прекратить перебор битиков -))

Answer (score 2):

Стандартное деление с вызовом функции __aeabi_uldivmod из GCC для ARM 10_3 - выполняется за 269 тиков DWT счётчика. Жирно.
Деление на 10 умножением дробным числом выполняется на 18% быстрее чем сдвигом. Существенную задержку вносит сохранение контекста в функции - слишком много регистров требуется для операций.

Деление умножением выполняется за 67 тика, и требует Cortex-M3/M4 и выше.

```
union divrev
{
    uint64_t w64;
    uint32_t w32[2];
};

__attribute__ ((optimize("-Og")))
uint64_t divu64_10(uint32_t* residue, uint64_t value)//72
{
    uint32_t res, t10, magh, magl;
    union divrev rev;
    union divrev rew;
    rev.w64 = value;
    magh = 3435973837UL; magl = 429496730UL; t10 = 10;
    rew.w32[1] = ((uint64_t)rev.w32[1] * magh >> 35);
    rew.w32[0] = 0;
    rev.w64 = (uint64_t)rev.w64 - rew.w64 * t10;
    res = ((uint64_t)rev.w64 >> 16);
    res = ((uint64_t)res * magl >> 32);
    rew.w32[0] = res << 16;
    rev.w64 = (uint64_t)rev.w64 - rew.w32[0] * t10;
    res = ((uint64_t)rev.w32[0] * magl >> 32);
    rew.w32[0] += res;
    res = rev.w32[0] - res * t10;
    *residue = res;
    return rew.w64;
};
```

Можно ускориться в 13 раз, если функция будет выдавать готовую строку.
char* tail_txt - это хвост массива, минимальный размер которого 24 байта.

```
char* u64_char (char* tail_txt, uint64_t value)//100
{
    uint32_t res, t10, magh, magl;
    union divrev rev;
    union divrev rew;
    rev.w64 = value;
    *tail_txt = 0;
    magh = 3435973837UL; t10 = 10; magl = 429496730UL;
    do{
        rew.w32[1] = ((uint64_t)rev.w32[1] * magh >> 35);
        rew.w32[0] = 0;
        rev.w64 = (uint64_t)rev.w64 - rew.w64 * t10;
        res = ((uint64_t)rev.w64 >> 16);
        res = ((uint64_t)res * magl >> 32);
        rew.w32[0] = res << 16;
        rev.w64 = (uint64_t)rev.w64 - rew.w32[0] * t10;
        res = ((uint64_t)rev.w32[0] * magl >> 32);
        rew.w32[0] += res;
        rev.w32[0] += '0';
        res = (rev.w32[0] - res * t10);
        *(--tail_txt) = res;
        rev.w64 = (uint64_t)rew.w64;
    }while (rev.w32[1]);
    if (rev.w32[0] == 0) return tail_txt;
    do{
        rev.w32[1] = ((uint64_t)rev.w32[0] * magh >> 32);
        res = rev.w32[0] + '0';
        rev.w32[0] = rev.w32[1] >> 3;
        res -=  rev.w32[0] * t10;
        *(--tail_txt) = res;
    }while (rev.w32[0]);
    return tail_txt;
};
```

Comment: Я правильно понял, что остаток будет в `rev`?

Comment: Остаток не вычисляется, на выхлопе результат делимого на 10.

Comment: Теперь вычисляется в ссылку &residue.