# Преобразование 8 байтового массива в строку

Tags: c

Есть число, которое хранится в 8 байтовом массиве, используется прямой порядок байт(BE). Требуется этот массив преобразовать в UNICODE строку. Интересует именно своя реализация, хотя я думаю в STL/CRT такого нету:

```
BYTE number[] = { 0x00, 0x2f, 0x49, 0x31, 0x6f, 0x53, 0xce, 0xdf};
WCHAR result[23];
```

В result должна оказаться строка "13309800575389407". Спасибо!

Comment: Это винда? Что вы называете UNICODE (UTF-8, UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE, ...)? Какой размер WCHAR (sizeof(WCHAR))? Вообще, сконвертировать ваш BE number в число -- `unsigned long long n = 0; for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) n = (n << 8) + number[i];` -- вывести в виде ascii в строку -- `char str[23]; sprintf(str, "%llu", n);`

Comment: -> Это винда? Что вы называете UNICODE (UTF-8, UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE, ...)?
Я использую typedef(WCHAR ) из заголовочного файла WinNT, значит очевидно это винда, юникод UTF-16LE, sizeof(WCHAR) = 2

Comment: Функцию sprintf я не могу использовать, CRT недоступно

Comment: Кстати мне кажется, что не получится использовать преобразование в 64 разрядное число, потому что у меня програ компилится на x86 архитектуре, значит что бы поддержать unsigned long long n, нужен crt, которого у меня нету

Comment: Если у вас процессор 64-бит арифметику не поддрживает (можно без умножения и деления (поскольку есть довольно эффективная функция деления на 10 с получением остатка)) , то ее придется писать самому, моделируя uint64_t, например, парой uint32_t. Т.е. проверьте, вы в своем компиляторе можете использовать, скажем, long long и операции сложения и сдвига с ним. / Понятно, что сам перевод ascii (десятичные цифры числа number всегда ascii) в UTF-16LE тривиален

Comment: Вот эта функция [деления на 10 с остатком](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/671733/232)

Comment: u64=0x002f49316f53cedf; печатается  как 13309800575389407.                            u64=0xdfce536f31492f00; печатается как 16126919052693679872.                                                          Вам нужно победить путаницу с определением прямого и обратного порядка байтов режима хранения (адресации) и для режима отображения на экране. Они разные и придирчивые.