# Получить Int64 из двух Int32 с помощью ограниченного числа операций

Tags: алгоритм

Int64 поступает на вход двумя кусками Int32. Можно ли как-то получить исходное число в строчном представлении в десятичном виде, имея только Int32 и операции + - * / MOD, битовые операции, сдвиги, цикл, условный оператор? Например, получить в одном Int32 младшие 9 десятичных цифр, в другом старшие, а потерей 4-5 двоичных разрядов можно пренебречь.

Пример: исходное число 78542365896558 поступает на вход как 18287 (старшее двойное слово) и 298954606 (младшее двойное слово). На выходе получить строку или два числа 78542 и 365896558.

Просто вычислитель такой - промышленный ПЛК. Язык программирования [Structured text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_text) - это для информации. Из вещественных - только float (single precision).  Есть массивы вещественных чисел. Ещё есть строковый тип данных, там только строковые константы, конкатенация и преобразование числа в строку и наоборот. Функция SELSTR - выбор по индексу одной из пяти строк.

Результат нужно представить в виде двух (или больше, если нужно) Int32 (как описано выше) или строки.

Можно смоделировать алгоритм на c* (c, c#, c++) или Python.

Сам думал, думал, решил только офлайн - для интерфейса верхнего уровня написал COM библиотеку, которая по двум Int32 возвращает строку. А хотелось бы реализовать это в контроллере.

Если кто-то заинтересуется задачей - могу выставить на конкурс за NNN баллов.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149616/discussion-on-question-by-rotabor--int64---int32---); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: Посмотрите на [программу получения остатков от деления на 10](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/671733/232) (используется для печати int64 в десятичном виде), может быть адаптируете под свою задачу

Comment: @avp Спасибо, похоже, что может подойти.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы упростить задачу, представим число в виде набора разрядов от старшего к младшему, тогда для перевода из системы с меньшим основанием в систему с большим достаточно просто брать по очереди разряды, умножать на основание и, в случае переполнения, добавлять новый разряд в результате.

Алгоритм:

```
result = 0;
FOR digit IN digits
    result = result * base + digit
END FOR
```

Для случая из задачи, когда на входе всего два числа, можно выбрать основание порядка 10<sup>9</sup> в этом случае для результата хватит трех переменных, которые будут играть роль разрядов

обработка входных чисел будет по порядку сначала старшего потом младшего.

Так заранее известно что числа 32 битные получать нужный двоичный разряд можно с помощью сдвигов

```js
function conv(i1, i2) {
  var x = 0,
    y = 0,
    z = 0;
  console.log(i1.toString(2).padStart(32, '0'))
  console.log(i2.toString(2).padStart(32, '0'))
  for (var i = 32; i-- > 0;) { // проходим по всем битам начиная со старшего
    var c = (i1 & (1 << i)) !== 0; // значение бита

    var valX = x * 2 + c; // умножаем на текущее значение и прибавляем бит
    x = valX % 10 ** 9; // обновляем значение 
    var valY = y * 2 + (valX - x) / 10 ** 9; // если нужно переносим разряд
    y = valY % 10 ** 9
    z = z * 2 + (valY - y) / 10 ** 9;
  }
  // повтор для младшего разряда
  for (var i = 32; i-- > 0;) { // проходим по всем битам начиная со старшего
    var c = (i2 & (1 << i)) !== 0; // значение бита
    var valX = x * 2 + c; // умножаем на текущее значение и прибавляем бит
    x = valX % 10 ** 9; // обновляем значение 
    var valY = y * 2 + (valX - x) / 10 ** 9; // если нужно переносим разряд
    y = valY % 10 ** 9
    z = z * 2 + (valY - y) / 10 ** 9;
  }
  return [x, y, z] // возврат всех трех разрядов - если итоговое число занимает меньше - будут 0
}

console.log(conv(18287, 298954606))
```

Comment: Спасибо! Супер!

Comment: @rotabor, раз уж ты не вычисляешь на каждом этапе счетчик тебе не нужен `i`. Достаточно проверить что `SHIFT1 > 0`

Comment: Логично. Убрал лишнее.

Comment: @rotabor, В принципе можно ускорить, если брать не по одному биту, а сразу несколько

Comment: Ха, пришлось повозиться. Нужно правильно подобрать размер входной и выходной систем счисления в зависимости от размеры выходных данных так, чтобы не было переполнения в промежуточных результатах.

Comment: "для перевода из системы с меньшим основанием в систему с большим" - это лишнее ограничение. Всё будет работать и при другом порядке оснований.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, не был уверен, казалось там делить надо а не множить ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy я бы сказал, что есть всего одна задача - представить число в заданной системе счисления. В какой СС выражено исходное число - совершенно неважно. Вычислитель (Твиссел :-)) производит вычисления в свой собственной СС. Если это современный ЦПУ, то это двоичная система, если человек - то это десятчная, а может и любая. На конечном этапе вычисленные остатки выражаются цифрами новой СС.

Answer (score 3):

#### Схема Горнера

На входе два числа (*d<sub>0</sub>* и *d<sub>1</sub>*), каждое из тридцати двух бит. Значение, которое они представляют есть *2<sup>32</sup>d<sub>1</sub> + d<sub>0</sub>*. *64* бита из этих двух чисел можно по разному нарезать на группы. Например, если группировать биты по тринадцать штук, получится другое представление того же числа: *(2<sup>13</sup>)<sup>5</sup>d'<sub>5</sub> + (2<sup>13</sup>)<sup>4</sup>d'<sub>4</sub> + (2<sup>13</sup>)<sup>3</sup>d'<sub>3</sub> + (2<sup>13</sup>)<sup>2</sup>d'<sub>2</sub> + 2<sup>13</sup>d'<sub>1</sub> + d'<sub>0</sub>*.

Если расставить скобки, получится схема Горнера: *([{(d'<sub>5</sub>2<sup>13</sup> + d'<sub>4</sub>)2<sup>13</sup> + d'<sub>3</sub>}2<sup>13</sup> + d'<sub>2</sub>]2<sup>13</sup> + d'<sub>1</sub>)2<sup>13</sup> + d'<sub>0</sub>*. Её можно переписать так:

*n<sub>6</sub> = 0*

*n<sub>5</sub> = n<sub>6</sub>2<sup>13</sup> + d'<sub>5</sub>*

*n<sub>4</sub> = n<sub>5</sub>2<sup>13</sup> + d'<sub>4</sub>*

*n<sub>3</sub> = n<sub>4</sub>2<sup>13</sup> + d'<sub>3</sub>*

*n<sub>2</sub> = n<sub>3</sub>2<sup>13</sup> + d'<sub>2</sub>*

*n<sub>1</sub> = n<sub>2</sub>2<sup>13</sup> + d'<sub>1</sub>*

*n<sub>0</sub> = n<sub>1</sub>2<sup>13</sup> + d'<sub>0</sub>*

Чтобы вычислить значение числа, нужно несколько раз повторить операцию *mul_add(f, t, n) -> n = nf + t*. Параметер *f* (factor - множитель) приравнивается к основанию системы счисления. Параметр *t* (term - слагаемое) перебирает цифры числа *d'<sub>i</sub>* от старших разрядов к младшим.

#### Школьная арифметика

Число *n* представлено как массив цифр *e<sub>i</sub>*. Операции умножения на число и сложение с числом делаются школьными алгоритмами - в столбик (деления целочисленные, *c<sub>i</sub>* - переносы):

*c<sub>0</sub> = t*

*e'<sub>0</sub> = (e<sub>0</sub>f + c<sub>0</sub>) mod 10; c<sub>1</sub> = (e<sub>0</sub>f + c<sub>0</sub>) / 10*

*e'<sub>1</sub> = (e<sub>1</sub>f + c<sub>1</sub>) mod 10; c<sub>2</sub> = (e<sub>1</sub>f + c<sub>1</sub>) / 10*

...

*e'<sub>i</sub> = (e<sub>i</sub>f + c<sub>i</sub>) mod 10; c<sub>i+1</sub> = (e<sub>i</sub>f + c<sub>i</sub>) / 10*

...

Алгоритм выше строит число в виде цепочки цифр, которую удобно печатать. *10* можно поменять на любую степень десятки, тогда каждая "цифра" будет хранить не один десятичный разряд, а несколько. Печать останется простой, количество операций может уменьшиться.

#### Выбор оснований систем счисления

Вычисления делаются в ограниченном типе - 32 разряда. Тип со знаком, верхний предел *2<sup>31</sup>*. Нужно убедится что выражение *e<sub>i</sub>f + c<sub>i</sub>* не приводит к переполнению.

Напомню что *f* - основание системы счисления - степень двойки. Пусть *f = 2<sup>k</sup>*. По индукции можно показать что *c<sub>i</sub> < f*.

"Цифры" *e<sub>i</sub>* ограничены степенью десятки. Введём *m*: *0 ≤ e<sub>i</sub> < 10<sup>m</sup>*.

Получаем ограничение *10<sup>m</sup>2<sup>k</sup> < 2<sup>31</sup>*. Или *10<sup>m</sup> < 2<sup>31-k</sup>*.

Выбирать *m* и *k* нужно как можно больше. Чем больше отдельные цифры, тем меньше их потребуется чтобы представить числа, тем меньше операций деления и умножения нужно будет для вычислений.

Например пусть *k = 5*, *m = 3*. Понадобится 13 двоичных цифр по пять разрядов чтобы покрыть 64 двоичных разряда. Нужно 7 десятичных цифр по три разряда чтобы покрыть 20 десятичных разрядов (*2<sup>63</sup> < 10<sup>20</sup> ≤ 2<sup>64</sup>*). Количество умножений и делений в алгоритме будет *13·7*.

Таблица для всех *k*:

> ```
>      число          число      число
>  k  двоичных  m  десятичных  умножений/
>       цифр          цифр      делений
>
>  1    64      9      3          192
>  2    32      8      3           96
>  3    22      8      3           66
>  4    16      8      3           48
>  5    13      7      3           39
>  6    11      7      3           33
>  7    10      7      3           30
>  8     8      6      4           32
>  9     8      6      4           32
> 10     7      6      4           28
> 11     6      6      4           24
> 12     6      5      4           24
> 13     5      5      4           20
> 14     5      5      4           20
> 15     5      4      5           25
> 16     4      4      5           20
> 17     4      4      5           20
> 18     4      3      7           28
> 19     4      3      7           28
> 20     4      3      7           28
> 21     4      3      7           28
> 22     3      2      10          30
> 23     3      2      10          30
> 24     3      2      10          30
> 25     3      1      20          60
> 26     3      1      20          60
> 27     3      1      20          60
> ```

Минимум (20 умножений) достигается для четырёх строк. Самая удобная *k = 16*, *m = 4*. Требуется четыре двоичные цифры и пять десятичных. Но главное - тридцатидвухбитные величины удобно разрезать на шестнадцатибитные половинки.

#### Код

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>


#define N_DIGITS 5
#define BASE_2 65536
#define BASE_10 10000


void print(uint32_t number[N_DIGITS]) {
    bool first = true;
    for (int i = N_DIGITS - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        if (!first || number[i] > 0) {
            if (first) {
                printf("%" PRIu32, number[i]);
            } else {
                printf("%04" PRIu32, number[i]);
            }
            first = false;
        }
    }
    if (first) {
        printf("0");
    }
    puts("");
}

// number = factor * number + term
void mul_add(uint32_t factor, uint32_t term, uint32_t number[N_DIGITS]) {
    uint32_t carry = term;
    for (int i = 0; i < N_DIGITS; ++i) {
        const uint32_t p = number[i] * factor + carry;
        number[i] = p % BASE_10;
        carry = p / BASE_10;
    }
    assert(carry == 0);
}

void convert(uint32_t low, uint32_t high, uint32_t number[N_DIGITS]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N_DIGITS; ++i) {
        number[i] = 0;
    }

    mul_add(BASE_2, high >> 16         , number);
    mul_add(BASE_2, high & (BASE_2 - 1), number);
    mul_add(BASE_2, low >> 16          , number);
    mul_add(BASE_2, low & (BASE_2 - 1) , number);
}

int main() {
    uint32_t high;
    scanf("%" SCNu32, &high);
    uint32_t low;
    scanf("%" SCNu32, &low);
    uint32_t number[N_DIGITS];
    convert(low, high, number);
    print(number);
}
```

Comment: Повезло Вашим студентам!

Comment: не знал что это "Схема Горнера" называется :)

Comment: @Grundy, число в позиционной системе счисления вычисляется как многочлен (цифры - коэффициенты) от основания. Чем не схема?

Answer (score 2):

Поскольку входное число разбито на части и есть ограничение на размер данных, то нужно определённым образом подобрать размер цифры на входе (ну, и размер на выходе тоже пришлось уточнить). Во-первых, размер цифры лучше сделать кратным размеру данных, чтобы не делать переносов двоичных разрядов из старшей части. Во-вторых, размер цифры на входе и на выходе нужно подобрать так, чтобы не было переполнения в промежуточных результатах.

Поэтому, оптимальным будет вариант со системой счисления с основанием 256 на входе и с четырьмя цифрами в системе счисления с основанием 1Е6 на выходе (с учетом того, чтобы основание выходной СС было кратно 1000):

```cs
    static string conv2(uint i1, uint i2) {
      uint x = 0, y = 0, z = 0, w = 0, c, valX, valY, valZ;
      for (uint i = 0xFF000000, j = 24; i > 0; i >>= 8, j -= 8) {
        c = (i1 & i) >> (int)j;
        valX = (x << 8) + c;
        x = valX % 1000000;
        valY = (y << 8) + (valX - x) / 1000000;
        y = valY % 1000000;
        valZ = (z << 8) + (valY - y) / 1000000;
        z = valZ % 1000000;
        w = (w << 8) + (valZ - z) / 1000000;
      }
      for (uint i = 0xFF000000, j = 24; i > 0; i >>= 8, j -= 8) {
        c = (i2 & i) >> (int)j;
        valX = (x << 8) + c;
        x = valX % 1000000;
        valY = (y << 8) + (valX - x) / 1000000;
        y = valY % 1000000;
        valZ = (z << 8) + (valY - y) / 1000000;
        z = valZ % 1000000;
        w = (w << 8) + (valZ - z) / 1000000;
      }
      var s = w == 0 ? z == 0 ? y == 0 ? "" : y.ToString() : z.ToString() + y.ToString("000000")
        : w.ToString() + z.ToString("000000") + y.ToString("000000");
      return s.Length == 0 ? x.ToString() : s += x.ToString("000000");
    }
```

Итак, вот что получилось:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
NUMBASE := 1000; I := 7;
WHILE I > 0 DO
    '^/DIGITS'[I][1] := 0;
    I := I - 1;
END_WHILE;
'^/SHIFT1' := 4278190080; I := 24;
WHILE '^/SHIFT1' > 0 DO
    DIGIT := SHR('^/MSINT' & '^/SHIFT1', I);
    J := 7;
    WHILE J > 0 DO
        V := '^/DIGITS'[J][1] * 256 + DIGIT;
        '^/DIGITS'[J][1] := V % NUMBASE;
        DIGIT := TRUNC((V - '^/DIGITS'[J][1]) / NUMBASE);
        J := J - 1;
    END_WHILE;
    '^/SHIFT1' := SHR('^/SHIFT1', 8); I := I - 8;
END_WHILE;
'^/SHIFT1' := 4278190080; I := 24;
WHILE '^/SHIFT1' > 0 DO
    DIGIT := SHR('^/LSINT' & '^/SHIFT1', I);
    J := 7;
    WHILE J > 0 DO
        V := '^/DIGITS'[J][1] * 256 + DIGIT;
        '^/DIGITS'[J][1] := V % NUMBASE;
        DIGIT := TRUNC((V - '^/DIGITS'[J][1]) / NUMBASE);
        J := J - 1;
    END_WHILE;
    '^/SHIFT1' := SHR('^/SHIFT1', 8); I := I - 8;
END_WHILE;
J := 1; REM далее перевод в строковое представление
WHILE J < 7 AND '^/DIGITS'[J][1] = 0 DO J := J + 1; END_WHILE;
'^/RESS' := " " + '^/DIGITS'[J][1]; J := J + 1;
WHILE J <= 7 DO
    IF '^/DIGITS'[J][1] = 0 THEN
        '^/RESS' := '^/RESS' + "000";
    ELSE
        I := 2 - TRUNC(LOG('^/DIGITS'[J][1]));
        WHILE I > 0 DO
            '^/RESS' := '^/RESS' + "0";
            I := I - 1;
        END_WHILE;
        '^/RESS' := '^/RESS' + '^/DIGITS'[J][1];
    END_IF;
    J := J + 1;
END_WHILE;
```

В окончательном варианте получилось 256 СС на входе и 1000 СС на выходе для того, чтобы можно было для цифр использовать массив float. Соответственно, 7 цифр.

Comment: Получится *32* (*= 8 * 4*) умножения/деления. Если взять *2^16* и *10^4*, будет *20* (*= 4 * 5*) операций умножения/деления.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Согласен, но на выходе чисел (разрядов) будет больше. Просто ориентировался на то, чтобы выходная СС была кратна 1000. Но, наверно, это ни к чему, всё равно преобразовываю результат в строку.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy кстати, а не должно ли 2^16 быть меньше 10^4?

Comment: Ограничений на отношение оснований нет. Их произведение должно помещаться в тип и это всё.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Да, точно. Входное число можно вообще не рабивать на части. Разбиение возникает из-за ограничения на тип данных.